# Track clicks on a button based on preceding button clicks

Tags: dynamic, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to track clicks on a button at the end of a sequence of selections. As shown in the image, there are five different business plans (circled in red), and each plan can be for three different years (highlighted in blue). The user will checkbox a business plan type (e.g., market trend) and click a year (e.g., 2017), then click the PDF button (highlighted in black) to download that particular plan (market trend for 2017 in this case).

[image]

So instead of counting the total clicks of PDF downloads, the task is to count how many times a particular plan is downloaded based on the plan type and year.

The PDF button, the checkbox for each plan type, and the click button for each year all can be tracked individually. They are also all on the same URL.

GTM and GA are used for tracking. Can anyone share some thoughts of how to achieve this type of tracking?

Thanks!
Yao

Comment: Did you manage to implement it?

Comment: Hi thanks for checking in but i am still trying to figure it out. I will post further questions under your post once i get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google tag manager you can use dataLayer.push() to push to an array which can be used to differentiate the clicks based on the interaction.
Approach is described here

[Google Analytics custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en)

In your particular case you could have the dataLayer configured to add the different key / values for the different report components and then the trigger will be configured to fire when the download button is clicked.

For example on each of the check boxes you could have:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="dataLayer.push({'plan_component': 'Market Trends'});">
```

You'd probably better having an array to store this info.

The resultant data can be viewed or aggregated via a custom report download. Described here.

[Custom Dimensions and Metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)

It can be a bit tricky to understand and you'll need to change the site so that the dataLayer gets populated with the requisite data but this is the way to go. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi bamdan, thanks for the lead and i have been reading it in the past few days. Unfortunately, still pretty much clueless. What confuses me the most is that a lot of articles talking about using a data layer snippet such as                                  
  <script>
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 window.dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'Plan component',
 'Type':'SWOT'
 });
</script>       I am not clear when to use data layer push that is built in a link vs. a snippet. I apologize in advance if this doesn't make a lot of sense - i am really lost here.

Comment: no worries. The dataLayer is just a global object which stores data in a form which tag manager can interact with. So if in your example you click a submit  button on a form you you can 'push' a value to the 'DataLayer'. Why would you do this? You can then define a trigger in tag manager UI to fire when this value is present. The reason behind this is that the logic of when and how to fire is abstracted away from the application and can be set via the UI. Generally this is preferable from a maintenance and legacy point of view https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164391?hl=en

Comment: Hi bamdan,thank you.I feel i am getting somewhere but still have few questions. I managed to use the code in your first reply to push the report component info to GTM when the checkbox for a particular report type is clicked. I am not clear about the next step as how to retrieve this information when the PDF download button is clicked. I assume it has to do with custom event trigger just cant figure out the steps. Can you please elaborate or a code example would be very helpful. I did read all the links you fowarded but no luck. Thank you in advance.